# Python - Find intersection between lines spanned by several points

Tags: python, linear-algebra, intersection

I have what I believe is a rather basic issue, to which I cannot find an elegant solution. Imagine I have two rather complex lines (e.g. B-splines) in 2-D space spanned up by two matrices of dimensions (n,2), where n (the rows) are the number of points along the lines, and the two columns correspond to x and y coordinate respectively. Further information:

- The distance between two sequential points is similar, but not constant.
- The point of intersection may not necessarily be a point that spans up the lines.
- there may be (theoretically) any number of intersections

I want to find the point(s) at which these lines intersect. For my purposes it is sufficient to take the lines as linear between each two sequential points.

Unfortunately, every solution I can come up with so far is incredibly inefficient (e.g. using two nested for-loops and checking each segment of two points on one line vs each segment on the other line). There has to be a more elegant way of doing this.

Is there any kind of function that may ease an implementation of such a routine?

P.S.: Below you can find an illustration of the system I described above.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a continous function, that creates these lines? Are the x points in the same distance and at the same positions?

Comment: If no to the questions above, you can do this iteratively with a binary tree search.

Comment: Not really continuous, no. The distance between the points is not constant. I'll google for binary tree search, thanks!

Comment: Could you give a little more information? Are these lines 2D splines with arbitrary number of intersections? Are these functions in a mathematical sense? All these information makes coding a lot easier. Newton-Raphson or equal should help finding intersections.

Comment: just implement recursive solution with this http://zonalandeducation.com/mmts/intersections/intersectionOfTwoLines1/intersectionOfTwoLines1.html ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'll edit the information in. The lines are based on 2D-B-splines (whose parameters I also have, but which are equally nasty to find the intersections of).

Comment: @netplay I am afraid that finding the intersection of two linear functions is not my primary problem. First, I have to find which two neighbouring points on each line provide the linear functions I have to intersect

Comment: The distance between points is not constant, but every point [x, y1] in one curve has an equivalent point [x, y2] in the other curve?

Comment: @Piinthesky unfortunately, that's also not the case. but it gives me a good idea: interpolating x between each line to make it so, then subtracting the y values from each other, then identifying the points where the sign changes! That might actually be the solution...

Comment: Maybe estimation with numpy ? 
http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/07/04/Estimating-where-two-functions-intersect-using-data/

Comment: By the way: Might the lines intersect themselves? Are you interested in these points as well?

Comment: https://folk.uio.no/martinre/Publications/intersection-preprint.pdf this might be a good read. Still tricky though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the responses, especially [Dschoni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1866177/dschoni) for relevant publication references, and [Piinthesky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8881141/piinthesky) for the comment that gave me the idea for the solution:

We join the X coordinates of the two line points into a common vector, then interpolate the Y coordinates for each of the two lines. Because we now have points at the same X positions, we can subtract the Y values from each other. Between points, at which the sign of the difference shifts, the lines intersect. Thanks everybody for the help!

Here's my solution code:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load data series
X1 = pickle.load(open("X1.p","rb"))
Y1 = pickle.load(open("Y1.p","rb"))
X2 = pickle.load(open("X2.p","rb"))
Y2 = pickle.load(open("Y2.p","rb"))

# Convert X vectors to lists, and merge them
X1_list = list(X1)
X2_list = list(X2)
in_first = set(X1_list)
in_second = set(X2_list)
in_second_but_not_in_first = in_second - in_first
result = X1_list + list(in_second_but_not_in_first)
X_joint = np.asarray(result) # Revert to array

# Create interpolated functions
line_1 = interp1d(X1, Y1, kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')
line_2 = interp1d(X2, Y2, kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')

# Create joint Ys
Y1_joint = line_1(X_joint)
Y2_joint = line_2(X_joint)

# Calculate difference in Y
difference = Y1_joint-Y2_joint

# Plot the original data series
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2)
axarr[0].plot(X1, Y1,'b')
axarr[0].plot(X2, Y2,'r')

# Plot the difference values
axarr[1].plot(X_joint,difference)
axarr[1].plot([min(X_joint),max(X_joint)],[0,0],'k')

# The intersections are where the difference graph dips below or rises above zero
```

Comment: Just for reference: This works as long as the two splines represent injective functions (or discrete representations thereof). It might not work for e.g. a spline describing a circle, because `f(x)` is no longer distinct.

Answer (score -1):

Interpolate each function f1, f2 linearly between two given data points. Minimize the function f = abs(f1 - f2) using a method that does not require derivatives, but keeps function evaluations low, e.g., [Brent's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method). The location of that minimum is your approximate intersection point. If you don't want to implement the algorithm yourself, use `scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html)).

Comment: But `min(abs(f1-f2))` returns the x value for the point with a minimal distance between the curves, not the intersection between the two nearest points.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the lines need not to be functions. So (f1-f2) might not be distinct.

Comment: Both comments do not apply with f1, f2 interpolated linearly between the data points... But I see that J.Galt figured that out

Comment: @rerx My comment does apply if `f` is not an injective function. Which is not given in the OP.

Comment: @Dschoni -- true, I had not thought of that!